# What's the lightest/fastest way to deliver data to mobile devices?

Tags: php, sql, database, mobile

I am looking for methods that let you deliver data to a user. This may be from XML to a flat-file DB to a relational DB.

This DB will be saved in a server and will serve handheld devices, smartphones and tablets on request. My main concern is the speed of displaying the requested info over millions of rows and how the data can be easily updated.

Before posting this, I made some Google searches pointing me to SQLite. What is your opinion about this ?

Comment: Of course I won't use an XML database with " over millions of rows".

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa That's for sure, but I wanted to show that I am open for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably be better off setting up a SOAP/XML-RPC service and working the data on the server and sending it to the client pieces at a time, caching as you go. This is going to be potentially the "fastest" way, since you don't have to transmit a large file to a handheld. It may not work for you, but it's worth mentioning.

This is essentially just a file download bracketed by an output to a transport format and an input to the mobile device's datastore. I imagine you're describing something like a dictionary, something that is fairly static.

The approach you're going to want to achieve will need to:

1. Take into account overall file size, ie, utilize as little meta description as you can get away with to communicate the data's meaningfulness.
2. Utilize some type of compression (gzip, for instance) of the data between the server and device. Consider that aggressive compression may take longer on the device to uncompress and be counter-productive to a less aggressive approach that's significantly faster.
3. Take into account how the data will get out of your server's storage (Is it in a database? Can you cache the data into the transport form?) into the device's data storage system (ie, SQLite). Going out of your way to compress the transfer speed significantly may in the end be counter-productive if the device has to work three times longer to insert the data than the time that was saved in downloading to the device.
4. Test. Test. Test.

You could serve it as a CSV or JSON-formatted file, which are very minimalistic; they don't use a lot of data to describe the data. XML is not the fastest because it is generally very descriptive, but has other advantages. Another option may be send a text file with the SQL insert statements.

Another "option", of course, may be to use the update mechanism and push it out as an "update". My thought on this is that many people with mobile devices know updates are time consuming and are often very large downloads, so they connect to their computer when doing so. This is just a thought; I'm not sure if this would actually be any better, but thought I'd throw it out there.

SQLite is an RDBMS that runs on many mobile platforms. It has it's limitations, but it may be all you have to work with. It's a good option.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the mobile devices to preform actions on the data(like offline processing) I think sql lite is the way to go.

if the processing gonna happen online anyway and the mobile device would be most for displaying and will be in an environment  where you are "always" online then Web services for requesting and processing the data and then a backend sql server would be the way to go

In tearms of preformance it is like this:
alot of data = alot of online traffic so if really alot of data like you said milions of rows then I think offline is the way to go otherwise the traffic would just kill the preformance

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with millions of rows and you want to display small samples at a time (anything else is hardly possible) on mobile devices, you should definitely do the processing at the server side, best using an RDBMS. Those are made for handling millions of rows. Sqlite is fast and simple, but in the millions-of-rows-range you'd better reach for PostgreSQL or one of the commercial brands (Oracle, MS SQL server, ..).

You can use a web service or direct access to the database, that depends. You can do some processing locally, but the selection of rows has to happen at the server.